# Change to user folder from the Command Prompt or PowerShell?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell, user-folders, home-folder

Is there anything that corresponds to the `~` character found in Linux. E.g. `CD ~\Downloads` to go to the user's download folder from anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing like `~` in Windows cmd, but you can use `%USERPROFILE%` or `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%` like `$HOME` in *nix. See

- [Recognized Environment Variables](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/usmt/usmt-recognized-environment-variables)
- [Windows Environment Variables](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html)

However in PowerShell you can use `~` like on Linux. `cd ~` will work as expected or you can shorten it to `cd` in PowerShell Core like how you can on Linux

> The tilde character (~) is shorthand notation for the current user's home folder. This example shows `Resolve-Path` returning the fully qualified path value.
>
> ```
> Resolve-Path ~
>
> Path
> ----
> C:\Users\User01
> ```
>
> [Resolve-Path](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/resolve-path?view=powershell-6)

> ```
> PS C:\> Push-Location ~ -StackName Stack2
> PS C:\Users\User01> Pop-Location -StackName Stack2
> PS C:\>
> ```
>
> The first command pushes the current location onto a new stack named Stack2, and then changes the current location to the home directory, represented in the command by the tilde symbol (`~`), which when used on a FileSystem provider drives is equivalent to `$HOME` and `$env:USERPROFILE`.
>
> [Push-Location](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/push-location?view=powershell-5.1)

In PowerShell Core `cd` alone without a location behaves exactly like on Linux where `cd` and `cd ~` both changes to the home directory

> - `-Path`
>
>   Specify the path of a new working location. If no path is provided, `Set-Location` defaults to the current user's home directory. When wildcards are used, the cmdlet chooses the first path that matches the wildcard pattern.
>
> [Set-Location](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-location?view=powershell-7.1)

Answer (score 1):

The `~` ([Tilde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde)) is a built in shortcut that autocompletes to the users 'Home' folder. Normally the home folder will be found under /home/ however it can infact be in almost any location on the system (including on network drives). This is defined in `/etc/passwd`.

So `cd ~/Downloads` is actually running the command `cd /home/<username>/Downloads`

Comment: Thanks for this, I did learn something, but this is tagged windows