# Is there an equivalent of ~ from Unix systems in Windows cmd.exe?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

The `~` character is a universal alias in the Unix word for referencing the home directory of the user. It is a special character that will be parsed and replaced by the full path of the current user's home directory. Is there an equivalent of this in cmd.exe ? (**not Powershell**)

Comment: Not really.. there is %UserProfile% which is similar to $HOME.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change to user folder from the Command Prompt or PowerShell?](https://superuser.com/questions/1221640/change-to-user-folder-from-the-command-prompt-or-powershell)

Comment: duplicates: [What is the equivalent of Linux's "~" (tilde) in Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/332871/241386), [Is there a shortcut command in Windows command prompt to get to the current user's home directory like there is in Linux?](https://superuser.com/q/168714/241386), [Is there a windows equivalent to using ~/ as a shorthand symbolizing your home/user directory?](https://superuser.com/q/476274/241386), [cmd equivalent to "cd ~" to change to `C:\Users\<current user>\Documents`](https://superuser.com/q/1048579/241386)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the equivalent of Linux's "~" (tilde) in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/332871/what-is-the-equivalent-of-linuxs-tilde-in-windows)

Comment: all the duplicates show the equivalent in cmd. not powershell, did you even read them?

Answer (score 18):

No.

You can use commands like `cd /D %homedrive%\%homepath%` or `cd /D %userprofile%` but typing them is just not the same even if end result is. The closest to the simplicity of `cd ~` I've ever seen is **[Señor CMasMas](https://superuser.com/users/1000631/se%C3%B1or-cmasmas)**'s elegant solution below.

Create a new bat file with one single line:

```
@cd /d %UserProfile% –
```

Save it with name `cd~.bat` into any folder in your %PATH%. After that you can get from anywhere in the system back to home directory by typing command

```
cd~
```

Comment: It is funny that you mention this.  I have a `cd~.bat` file in my path that has one line in it.. `@cd /d %UserProfile%`

Comment: That's the most elegant solution I've ever seen :D

Comment: Be aware that `%homepath%` does not include the drive, just the path relative to that drive. `%homedrive%` contains the drive letter.

Comment: @RossPresser Good point, let's update the answer :-)

Comment: Batch file from batch file should be called via `call` command.

Comment: In Unix you wouldn't even type `cd ~`, just `cd` because `$HOME` is already the default destination.  `~` is useful when you're cd'ed somewhere else and want to reference a file in your home dir, e.g. `vim ~/notes.txt` or `cp -a foo ~/bin/`.  (Or in a script where you *might* be.)  Anyway, isn't `%homedrive%\%homepath%` basically equivalent to `$HOME`, expanding an environment variable?  When you say it's "not the same", do you mean it's too long to type?

Comment: @PeterCordes Yap, I generally drop the tilde except in scripts, `cd ~` just has a bit of charming nostalgia :-) And of course written down `cd` and `cd ~` don't mean the same thing. `%homedrive%\%homepath%` as concept is more `/users/$USER`, `%UserProfile%` is more `$HOME`, methinks. I updated the answer again.

Comment: In Unix, `cd` and `cd ~` *do* mean the same thing.  Tilde expansion happens after word splitting, so even if your `$HOME` contains spaces, it still works like `cd "$HOME"` instead of breaking.  Maybe you meant in Windows?  I don't know Windows `cmd.exe` very well.

Comment: They do, _typed in shell_, but "typed in shell" != "written down". Writing on a paper, forum etc. `cd` = "change directory", but `cd ~` = "change directory to $HOME". That's what I meant :-)